# angular 5 not displaying an array

Tags: angular

I've got a form, and Im adding items to an array - I want to display that array on the form below where the items are added, so the user has feedback...

If I display the full form value, I see the array just fine, however if I try to display ONLY the array, nothing shows up - and no errors.

so

```
{{ form.value | json }}
```

gives me this:

```
{
    myArray: ["some value","another value"]
}
```

and if I try to do this:

```
{{ form.myArray }} or {{ form.myArray.value }}
```

I get nothing...

Any help is appreciated

Excellent answers - thanks - however

```
{{ form.value.myArray }}
```

Only gives me the first element, I want the whole array (as a list), what might I be doing wrong now.

Comment: form.value[myArray][0] try this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
{{ form.value.myArray }}
```

and if you need the first element,

```
{{ form.value.myArray[0] }}
```

Comment: Excellent answers - thanks - however 

    {{ form.value.myArray }}

Only gives me the first element, I want the whole array (as a list), what might I be doing wrong now.

Comment: then you need to loop

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to

`{{form.value[myArray][0]}}` //to access first element in array

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
<div *ngFor = "let elm of form.value.myArray">
{{elm}}
</div>
```

Or to diaplay all use:

```
{{form.value.myArray}}
```